# Why does this formula work?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, periodic-trends

My teacher gave us a formula for determining if a M-O-H like compound will act like a base or not.without explaining much.

Base if:$$|\chi_o-\chi_M|\gt|\chi_o-\chi_H|$$
Flipped inequality if acid.

I am not unable to understand why the formula works.I think its because if the diffrence in electronegativity between Oxygen and element m is high.
It is  more likely for M-O-H to break into M and O-H
.Not certain about that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bond with greater electronegativity difference has greater tendency to break with help of polar $\ce{H2O}$ molecules to hydrated ions, unless it is ionic already. Electrons then stay at the oxygen as the most electronegative atom from all the three.

So if $\ce{M}$ is less electronegative then $\ce{H}$, there will be'

$$\ce{M^{(+)}-O^{(-)}-H(aq) <=> M+(aq) + OH-(aq)}$$

but if $\ce{M}$ is more electronegative than $\ce{H}$ , then there will be:

$$\ce{M-O^{(-)}-H^{(+)}(aq) + H2O <=> MO-(aq) + H3O+(aq)}$$

( The charge in parenthesis is a partial charge.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you explained it very well. Can you tell me a possible reason why my post was downvoted? I don't use chem SE much and I would like to improve upon the framework of my questions.

Comment: Hard to tell. The most probable reason may be the downvoter considers it not enough elaborated by explicit own thoughts based on prior search of available resources.